# Eclipse EE "ports 8081 and 8009 " in use and needed by Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, zk

I keep getting errors in eclipse when I try run the internal tomcat.

"ports 8081 and 8009 " in use. However those ports are free. Any ideas what to try next?

Its a ZK application I am trying to run

Comment: @kmas results negative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe Tomcat is already running on that port? Have you tried some other ports?

Comment: how do you change the port in Eclipse?

Comment: its in server.xml which should be in \conf\

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way to know the program, use `netstat -ao`

You have the port and the associated pid.

Get the pid for 8009 and 8081 ports.

Then launch `taskmgr`

Show column `pid` (Menu > Select > Column selection > check PID)

- You know the program which uses these ports.
- Kill them
- Launch Tomcat in eclipse.

Comment: So which program was it ? :)